# Remove All Occurrences of a Given Value from a Doubly Linked List

Tags: java

Alright, so cut a long story short, what I'm trying to do here is remove all instances of value e from a doubly linked list. As far as I know, my logic is at least mostly right, but for some off reason it isn't actually removing any of the nodes in my test cases.

```
public boolean removeAll(int e) {

    DIntNode dummy = head,next = null; 
    if (head == null)
        return false;
    while (dummy != null) {
        if (dummy.getData() == e) {
            next = dummy.getNext();
            dummy.getNext().setPrev(null);
            dummy = next;
            return true;
        }
        else 
            dummy = dummy.getNext();
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is what I currently have for my code of the metho. My logic here was to use a dummy DIntNode that starts at the head and a "next" node to help me shrink the list, so to speak. In other words, if the list was something like "1<-> 1 <-> 2 <-> 3", the function would change it to "2<->3", in theory. The reason this is a boolean function is because I'm required to return true if the given value is removed form the list.

Is there just another step in the logic that I'm missing, or is the methodology itself just unreliable?  I'm very unsure at this point, so any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that if you have a _doubly_ linked list you need to propery set `prev` as well. Basically when removing a node you do the following if `prev` and `next` are not null (otherwise adjust accordingly, i.e. if there's no `prev` you just ignore that part etc.): `current.prev.next = current.next` and `current.next.prev = current.prev`. That way you effectively remove `current` from the chain - unless `current` is the head in which case you'd need to set `head = current.next` as well.

Answer (score 2):

You set

> dummy.getNext().setPrev(null);

But previous node also have reference to next node you try to remove. You should set this reference to next active value.
That because when you want to get all linked list previous value still know about node you remove, because of next node reference

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code:

```
if (dummy.getData() == e) {
    DIntNode temp = dummy.getPrevious();
    temp.next = dummy.getNext();
    temp = dummy.getNext();
    temp.previous = dummy.getPrevious();
    return true;
 }
```

This used the previous reference. So the previous node will now have reference to the next node of your dummy node (node to be deleted). And similarly, the next node of dummy node will have reference of previous node of your dummy node. So, the dummy node will loose its connection/link from its doubly link list and that's what we want!

Please try.

Answer (score 0):

The method exits after the first encounter of 'e'.

If you want to remove all instances of 'e', then you should have something like this:

```
boolean listChanged = false;
while (dummy != null) {
    if (dummy.getData() == e) {
      // update list
      ...
      listChanged = true;
    }
    ...
}
return listChanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with the code:

1. When relinking a *doubly linked list*, where removing B from A - B - C, you need to set the next node for A to be C **as well as** the previous node for C to be A. With trying to keep you method names:

   `A.setNext(current.getNext());`

   `C.setNext(current.getPrev());`
2. With your code, if you find an occurrence, you `return`, which means that no other instances will be removed since you jump out of that method. You will probably need a new `boolean removed` variable, that is set to `false`, `return true` changed to `removed = true` and `return false` changed to `return removed`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should not write your code like this:

```
dummy.getNext().setPrev(...); // throws NPE if next is null
```